# c++ debugging: debug statements from console

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, lldb, tensor

I am using lldb on a mac. Trying to see intermediate tensor outputs in the marian library.

Statements like debug(tensor, ""); work when I put then in the code and run them, (they show a nice np array style view of the tensor), but when I run them from the DEBUG CONSOLE I get the following error message

```cpp
debug(output, "ads");
warning: Stopped in a C++ method, but 'this' isn't available; pretending we are in a generic context
error: <user expression 5>:1:1: no matching function for call to 'debug'
debug(output, "ads");
^~~~~
note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'const char [4]' to 'const std::__1::string' (aka 'const std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >') for 2nd argument
```

Is there a way to allow this interactivity, or make the tensor display show up in the left gutter where some local variables are displayed?

Answer (score 0):

The routine you are trying to call works when you use it in source even though the function takes a std::string and you are passing it a C string because the compiler knows how to convert a C string ("ads") into a std::string.  lldb's expression parser is not smart enough to do type coercion like this.

Even if it were smart enough to try that, making template instantiations is also not a trivial operation, and one that lldb's expression parser is only starting to learn how to do.  If there's a version of your debug function that takes a C string, you could use that.  Or maybe you could add, in your code, a wrapper that actually takes a C string.  That you should be able to call easily in the expression parser.

I don't know enough about marian to answer the second part of your question.  What storage does this tensor have?  Is it an argument to the functions you are interested in, is it a local variable, or in some global store?

BTW, the fact that the expression parser said:

```
warning: Stopped in a C++ method, but 'this' isn't available; pretending we are in a generic context
```

likely means that you are debugging optimized code, since at -O0 the compiler generally keeps `this` alive for the entire function.  If you need to debug the optimized version, for instance because the unoptimized code is too slow to be useful, then that's your fate.  But in debugging optimized code you often won't have access, in the debugger, to all the variables defined in your code.